How can I clear out value of text boxes after a submit event?
I have this simple form and want to clear out the text box values after a successful submit.  What I'm trying isn't working.  The only way I can clear them is to refresh the page. This should be something simple that I'm missing?
 const [postdata, setPostdata] = useState({
   name: '',
   desc: ''
   })

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"  onChange={handleInput} />
  <input type="text" name="desc" placeholder="Desc" onChange={handleInput} />
  <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
   setPostdata({ ...postdata, [event.target.name]: '' })
   }


Why not you simply set an id for the form (for example "myform") and then call document.getElementById("myform").reset()?

I'm trying to do it in a React-centric way

Use your state to drive the input values:
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" value={postdata.name} onChange={handleInput} />
<input type="text" name="desc" placeholder="Desc" value={postdata.desc} onChange={handleInput} />

And reset that state to empty values whenever you like:
setPostdata({
  name: '',
  desc: ''
});


Out of curiosity, I tried this less verbose way but it doesn't work.   Is this the same thing?
setPostdata({ ...postdata, [event.target.name]: '' })

@John: No, that's not the same thing.  When you debug that, what is the value of event.target.name?  What specifically are you expecting that line of code to do and why specifically do you expect it?  Are you familiar with the syntax of what that line of code is doing?

I understood it to be the name of the field and thought the spread operator would assign the empty string to each field in the object.  I'm obviously wrong.

@John: "I understood it to be the name of the field" - Don't assume, debug and observe.  This is happening on a submit event at the <form> level, so which one field should it contain and why?  Or should it contain none of the fields?  Or something else?  Debug and observe.  "the spread operator would assign the empty string to each field" - Why?  What empty string?  The spread operator doesn't assign empty strings, and no documentation or examples suggest that.  It assigns the fields/values on the object given.  So whatever fields/values are on postdata are what's being used.

Well the empty string in the expression. "" etc.  I am using that expression in an OnChange event to populate postdata.  But thinking further, that's only the field being changed and not the form as a whole.

I should say I'm using it this way...
setPostdata({ ...postdata, [event.target.name]: event.target.value })

@John: You're using an empty string to populate a specific field.  (A field whose name you don't know because you didn't check what the runtime value of event.target.name is.)  That field will be added to the new object being created in addition to the fields added from the spread operation.  As an academic exercise, you may want to create and test operations like this in isolation to observe their results.  Testing and observing is always more effective than guessing.
